# uitextview allow return key along with acceptable characters

Tags: string, uitextview, xcode9, enter

I'm trying to include the return key character as an acceptable key in the uitextview object. I use this code to filter only the desired characters:

```
#define ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS @" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!~`@#$%^&*-+();:=_{}[],.<>?\\/|\"\'0123456789"
NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:Regex] invertedSet];
NSString *filtered = [[textView.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
textView.text = filtered;
```

I tried adding "\^N" to the acceptable characters but the view does not allow it. I've also enabled the return key in the inspector. I hope anyone could help me with this....